# BeautifulSoup: html-encode special characters

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to html-encode all text in heading and p elements in an HTML file with BeautifulSoup.

```py
parser = BeautifulSoup('file.html', "html.parser")
pars = parser.find_all(['p', 'h1', 'h2', 'h3'])
for p in pars:
    if p.string != None:
        p.string = p.string.encode('ascii', 'xmlcharrefreplace')
```

This yields the following error: `AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'parent'`. So I found that `encode` returns a `byte` object. If I then decode it in ASCII:

```py
p.string = p.string.encode('ascii', 'xmlcharrefreplace').decode('ascii')
```

I don't the same error, but then in some case, but instead HTML entities are displayed litterally.

Obviously, I'm not handling this right. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

There was a smarter way, when saving the file:

```py
with open(file, "w", encoding="ascii") as f:
    f.write(str(parser.encode('ascii').decode()))
```